# emacs slow to start read/poll/writev /org/freedesktop /org/gnome

Tags: gnome, emacs, freedesktop

On a Linux CentOS system where I am a non-root user, every time I start emacs-24.5 it takes about 30 seconds to show up:

```
strace -tt -o emacs.strace ~/local/bin/emacs-24.5
```

There are some read/pool/writev entries that seem to mention /org/freedesktop and /org/gnome in there, and it times out after 30 seconds, but I can't tell what's going on:

```
[...]
11:17:14.251692 write(4, "BEGIN\r\n", 7) = 7
11:17:14.251730 poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLOUT}])
11:17:14.251774 writev(4, [{"l\1\0\1\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0n\0\0\0\1\1o\0\25\0\0\0/org/fre"..., 128}, {"", 0}], 2) = 128
11:17:14.251829 poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 25000) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
11:17:14.252008 read(4, "l\2\1\1\t\0\0\0\1\0\0\0=\0\0\0\6\1s\0\4\0\0\0:1.0\0\0\0\0"..., 2048) = 258
11:17:14.252072 read(4, 0x186c310, 2048) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
11:17:14.252153 writev(4, [{"l\1\0\1\0\0\0\0\2\0\0\0_\0\0\0\1\1o\0\20\0\0\0/org/gno"..., 112}, {"", 0}], 2) = 112
11:17:14.252209 poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 25000) = 0 (Timeout)
11:17:39.276732 writev(4, [{"l\1\0\1\0\0\0\0\3\0\0\0_\0\0\0\1\1o\0\20\0\0\0/org/gno"..., 112}, {"", 0}], 2) = 112
11:17:39.276933 poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 25000) = 0 (Timeout)
11:18:04.299584 writev(4, [{"l\1\0\1\0\0\0\0\4\0\0\0_\0\0\0\1\1o\0\20\0\0\0/org/gno"..., 112}, {"", 0}], 2) = 112
11:18:04.299693 poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 25000) = 0 (Timeout)
11:18:29.322840 writev(4, [{"l\1\0\1\0\0\0\0\5\0\0\0_\0\0\0\1\1o\0\20\0\0\0/org/gno"..., 112}, {"", 0}], 2) = 112
11:18:29.322988 poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 25000) = 0 (Timeout)
11:18:54.339815 writev(4, [{"l\1\0\1\0\0\0\0\6\0\0\0_\0\0\0\1\1o\0\20\0\0\0/org/gno"..., 112}, {"", 0}], 2) = 112
11:18:54.339982 poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 25000) = 0 (Timeout)
11:19:19.364735 writev(4, [{"l\1\0\1\0\0\0\0\7\0\0\0_\0\0\0\1\1o\0\20\0\0\0/org/gno"..., 112}, {"", 0}], 2) = 112
11:19:19.364810 poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 25000) = 0 (Timeout)
11:19:44.384454 poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
11:19:44.384515 writev(3, [{"\2\1\4\0|\1\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\0B\0\2O\4\0|\1\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\0\2\0"..., 44}, {NULL, 0}, {"", 0}], 3) = 44
[...]
```

Incidentally, I noticed that in this machine, I have a bunch of gconfd-2 processes accumulating over time:

```
username   770  0.2  0.0 128432   428 ?        S    Sep07  58:09 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
username  3096  0.2  0.0 128432   428 ?        S    Sep02  73:37 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
username  5966  0.1  0.0 128432  2280 ?        S    10:51   0:03 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
username  6171  0.2  0.0 128432   428 ?        S    Sep07  58:51 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
username  6339  0.1  0.0 128432  2028 ?        S    Sep26   2:36 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
username  6524  0.2  0.0 128432   428 ?        S    Sep02  73:32 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
username  6954  0.2  0.0 128432   444 ?        S    Sep09  52:29 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
username  7067  0.2  0.0 128432   428 ?        S    Sep06  62:02 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
username  8035  0.1  0.0 128436  2280 ?        S    11:17   0:00 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
username  8478  0.1  0.0 128436  2284 ?        S    11:17   0:00 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
username 16077  0.2  0.0 128432   416 ?        S    Sep05  64:07 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
username 18245  0.1  0.0 128432  2280 ?        S    11:02   0:02 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
username 18721  0.2  0.0 128432   428 ?        S    Sep09  52:53 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
username 19247  0.2  0.0 128432   416 ?        S    Sep02  73:51 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
username 20655  0.1  0.0 128432  2280 ?        S    10:55   0:02 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
username 21503  0.1  0.0 128432  2280 ?        S    10:55   0:02 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
username 22662  0.1  0.0 128432  2264 ?        S    Sep26   1:52 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
username 23035  0.2  0.0 128432   416 ?        S    Sep05  64:54 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
username 25380  0.1  0.0 128432  2280 ?        S    10:49   0:03 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
username 25445  0.1  0.0 128432  2172 ?        S    Sep26   2:03 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
username 25528  0.1  0.0 128432  2024 ?        S    Sep26   2:43 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
username 26399  0.1  0.0 128432  2268 ?        S    09:06   0:13 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
username 26585  0.0  0.0 103252   856 pts/6    S+   11:22   0:00 grep gconfd
username 26752  0.2  0.0 128432   432 ?        S    Sep09  52:17 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
username 28597  0.2  0.0 128432   432 ?        S    Sep09  52:07 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
username 29638  0.1  0.0 128432  2176 ?        S    Sep26   2:03 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
```

Any ideas what might be going on? Is there a way to call emacs maybe differently so that this does not keep happening?

EDITED: More details

This is a CentOS system which I ssh into, I presume uses gnome because I ssh from an Ubuntu 14.04 system with gnome on it:

```
cat /etc/centos-release 
CentOS release 6.2 (Final)
```

As I said, this is on a system where I am just a user, non-root access, so if there is a way for me to fix the issue on my end and not having to bother the sysadmin, that would be great.

Comment: I think you should only have one `gconfd-2` per login. If they are all yours you should try killing them (except the latest). Do you login at the screen, or by ssh? Are you using gnome? What version of CentOS is it?